# Error when signing up to my web application java

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a java web application that allows users to search contents, when i try to sign-up a new user i get the following message!

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    DBConnector.queries.selectUserNamePass(queries.java:30)
    Users.signupS.processRequest(signupS.java:42)
    Users.signupS.doPost(signupS.java:109)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

any one has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: *"any one has an idea how to solve it?"* hard to help you without seeing even a bit of code. Are we supposed to guess?

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    DBConnector.queries.selectUserNamePass(queries.java:30)
```

So open this class. Put a breakpoint on line 30, or before it. Then run your application in debug mode, step by step (F8 key). And you will find what cause NullPointerException.